# Solidity default constructor with address parameter

Tags: mapping, solidity

As I'm learning Solidity I'm struggling to understand how the `isApprovedForAll` function below actually works.

In particular I'd like to understand how calling the default `ProxyRegistry` constructor with an `address` parameter creates an initial `mapping`, what that initial mapping looks like, and why I should expect the if statement to ever return true.

The code is taken from an official OpenSea api example.

```
contract OwnableDelegateProxy {}

contract ProxyRegistry {
    mapping(address => OwnableDelegateProxy) public proxies;
}

contract SomeContract {

    address proxyRegistryAddress;

    constructor(
        address _proxyRegistryAddress
    ) {
        proxyRegistryAddress = _proxyRegistryAddress;
    }

    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator)
        public
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
```

This line does not call the `ProxyRegistry` constructor. It creates a helper object *(named `proxyRegistry`)* pointing to the `proxyRegistryAddress` address, and assumes there's a contract implementing functions defined in the `ProxyRegistry` contract.

In this case, it might be less confusing to just define `interface ProxyRegistry {` instead of the `contract ProxyRegistry {`.

But if you wanted to deploy the `ProxyRegistry` contract to a new address and call its constructor, you'd need use the `new` keyword:

```
new ProxyRegistry(<constructor_params>);
```

---

```
if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
    return true;
}
```

This snippet calls the [autogenerated](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#getter-functions) getter function `proxies(address)` on the remote contract, retrieving the mapping value by its key. And if the remote mapping value equals the `operator` value, it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks, that is very clear and helpful. One last thing I'm not quite getting is the creation of the "helper object". Could you point me to a documentation the explains this in a bit more detail, or compare it to something in another more mainstream language?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/control-structures.html#external-function-calls) seems to only cover "external function calls" for two cases combined - calls on the same contract, and calls on remote contracts. Which makes sense in the low-level approach (how the EVM processes the bytecode instructions), but it might be a bit confusing for people learning Solidity without prior knowledge of the EVM mechamisms. That's one of the reasons I made up the "helper object" term (I also use it in few other answers).

Comment: Example compared to web/mobile app development: You can think of remote contract calls as calls to a remote API from your app. Your local `proxyRegistry` holds two types of information - the API base URL (the external contract address), and the list of endpoints including their expected inputs and outputs (the `ProxyRegistry` function definitions). By invoking the `proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)` snippet in your app, you call a specific endpoint on external API (in this case the `proxies(address)` function on the remote contract) and it returns the output data in an expected format.